# Multiple forms with one page in tipfy

Tags: google-app-engine, forms, webforms, tipfy, multiple-forms

I haven't been able to find an example of using multiple forms on one 
page (or one Handler) for **tipfy**. I'm trying to allow users to both 
*answer* (form 1) and *comment* on an item (form 2) from the same 
page.

One approach to [doing this in PHP](http://bavotasan.com/tutorials/processing-multiple-forms-on-one-page-with-php/) is submitting a hidden form and checking for it before processing. However, I'm not sure what to check for in **tipfy**.

What's the best way to accomplish multiple forms in **tipfy**?